# Equivalence of two definitions of cross product for cohomology

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Allen Hatcher's book gives two versions of the cross product. 
The first one is: 
\begin{eqnarray}
a\times b\equiv p_1^*(a)\cup p_2^*(b), 
\end{eqnarray}
in which $p_1:X\times Y\rightarrow X$, $p_2:X\times Y\rightarrow Y$, $a\in H^m(X;R)$ and $b\in H^n(Y;R)$. The cup product is defined conventionally as
\begin{eqnarray}
\varphi\cup\psi(\sigma)=\varphi(\sigma|_{[v_0,\cdots,v_m]})\psi(\sigma|_{[v_m,\cdots,v_{m+n}]}). 
\end{eqnarray}
The second definition is
\begin{eqnarray}
(a\times b)(e_\alpha^m\times e_\beta^n)\equiv a(e_\alpha^m)b(e_\beta^n), 
\end{eqnarray}
by the help of the cellular cohomology and $e_\alpha^m\times e_\beta^n$ is given by the direct product of mappings in the cellular homology.

Allen Hatcher's book in Sec. 3.B shows that these two definitions are the same up to a potential sign difference, but I cannot obtain this sign ambiguity. My question is whether these two definitions are actually totally equivalent or modulo a sign? What is this sign difference quantitatively?